# Japanese and chinese characters in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, character-encoding, nsarray

I just had an error, at least different in Xcode.
I tried to put support for another language in a few sentences of the app, when the user chooses to change the language the app accesses just another index of NSArray.
What happens is that one of the languages ​​is Japanese, and ran a few sentences, others simply returned me the following:

```
 (
    "\U5f62\U5f0f",
    "\U9023\U63a5\U5230\U5176\U4ed6\U5730\U65b9",
    "\U884c\U674e\U8a8d\U9818",
    "\U9322"
)
```

The original NSArray was:

```
JapaneseTableTitles = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"あなたが聞こえます",@"便利なフレーズ",@"語彙",@"対話",@"情報", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you `NSLog`ging it? This is correct, as those are simply the Unicode code points of the Japanese/Chinese characters. If you do present those NSString in the UI (e.g. in a UILabel) they should appear correctly.

```
"\U5f62\U5f0f" = "形式"
"\U9023\U63a5\U5230\U5176\U4ed6\U5730\U65b9" = "連接到其他地方"
"\U884c\U674e\U8a8d\U9818" = "行李認領"
"\U9322" = "錢"
```

Comment: Hi Kenny, when I NSLog HTTP requests response string and it appears as "ÃÂ£ÃÂÃÂ¯ÃÂ£Ãâ¬ÃÂÃÂ£ÃÂÃâÃÂ£ÃÂ" and something different appears on LAbel but not the same as I expect in Japanese format. What should I check now? Thanks.

Comment: Did it Kenny - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316813/ios-handling-unicode-characters-from-http-request Thanks.